# ResolveUrl Illegal Characters in Path

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the error by this code

```
 <script runat="server" type="text/javascript" src='<%# ResolveUrl("js/excanvas.min.js") %>'></script>
```

Please note i am using runat="server" and it is really required.

Any help is appreicated

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need `runat="server"`?

Comment: No Need runat="server"

Comment: I need it. Else i got the viewstate invalid error. I am using DevExpress Control so there is no option

Comment: @SLaks I had added the comment

Comment: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B212856

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any illegal character but If you're not in data binding context you should use `<%=` isntead of `<%#`

```
src='<%= ResolveUrl("js/excanvas.min.js") %>'
```

As a side note, `runat="server"` is not required for this case

Comment: I am not sure but it think when using runat="server" cause this error to appear

Comment: Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Illegal characters in path.

Comment: This is the only error that is coming and i need runat="server"

Comment: @Moons: are you sure this line is generating that error? What happens if you remove it just for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem, DevExpress controls do not allow Page.Header.Databind as it invalidates the viewstate so you can't use `<%# ResolveUrl() %>` and `runat=server` does not work for `<script>` tags. To get around this problem, use the following:

For `<link>` tags, simply add runat=server and use the tilde:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/styles.css" type="text/css" runat="server" />
```

For `<script>` tags, ensure your `<head>` tag includes runat=server then do the following:

```
<head runat="server">
    <asp:Literal ID="jsJquery" runat="server" />
</head>
```

In code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.jsJquery.Text = "<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""" & Page.ResolveUrl("~/jscript/jquery.js") & """></script>"
End Sub
```